# How do I query a specific range of Firebase's analytics table using Data Studio's date parameters?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

I've been reading up on how to query a wildcard table in BigQuery, but Data Studio doesn't seem to recognize the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` keyword.

- [Google Data Studio on using parameters](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005)
- [Google BigQuery docs on querying wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#scanning_a_range_of_tables_using_table_suffix)

I'm trying to use the recently added date parameters for a custom query in Data Studio. The goal is to prevent the custom query from scanning all partitions to save time.

When using the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `project-name.analytics_196324132.events_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN DS_START_DATE AND DS_END_DATE
```

I receive the following error:

```
Unrecognized name: _TABLE_SUFFIX
```

I expected the suffix keyword to be recognized so that the custom query is more efficient. But I get this error message. Does Data Studio not yet support this? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible that you are setting the query in the wrong place. I created a DataSource from a Custom Query and the wildcard worked. The query I tested was the following, similar to yours since _TABLE_SUFFIX is a [wildcard that is available in standardSQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#querying_sets_of_tables_using_wildcard_tables) in BigQuery:

```
select  
    * 
from 
    `training_project.training_dataset.table1_*` 
where  
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190625' AND '20190626'
```

As per your comments you are trying to add a query in the formula field of a custom parameter, however the formula field only accepts [basic math operations, functions, and branching logic](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en&ref_topic=7570421).

The workaround I can see is to build a select query and use it as a Custom Query in the Data Source definition so that the query can calculate any extra fields in advance (steps 5,6 and 7 from [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio#create_a_chart_using_a_custom_query)).